# Как сделать логотип на сайте гиперссылкой на главную страницу?

Tags: python, django

Провел настройку статический файлов. Логотип на сайт подгрузился корректно.

`<img src="{% static 'main/img/logo.png' %}" alt="Лого">`

Как сделать его гиперссылкой на главную страницу?

Comment: Пробовали оборачивать изображение в `<a></a>`?

Comment: нет, я пока еще в поисках решения :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Осмелюсь предположить, что вам может подойти такой вариант

`<a href=""><img src="{% static 'main/img/logo.png' %}" alt="Лого"></a>`

Comment: в <a href="" должна располагаться сама ссылка? Правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Все верно, обычно в таких случаях указывают `/`. Чтобы вернуться на главную страницу.

Comment: благодарю, все работает